# Can't debug a local app engine PHP app with PHPStorm and Xdebug

Tags: google-app-engine, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm on a Mac and I've installed the latest version of the App Engine PHP SDK (1.9.19 - 2015-04-13) which include support for XDebug (since 1.9.18).
I'm using the latest version of PHPStorm (8.0.3) with the GAE plugin.

I've no trouble to run my app through PHPStorm but I can't get the debugger working *automatically* (will explain what it means few lines below).

Each time I try to debug my app, the debugger pane stays saying "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '11634' " (the ide key is always a random number).
No breakpoints are triggered, and when I stop the execution, a little red popup displays: "debug connection with xdebug was not established"...

[I've tried what the Google documentation suggests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/devserver#PHP_Local_debugging_with_XDebug) and it didn't work either.

Finally after hours of trying almost anything (compiling my own version of XDebug, checking every conf file, overriding php.ini to ensure paths to XDebug is correct and XDebug is on, etc...) I found a "workaround"...

The only way I can't get the debugger to work is to launch the app, then go to the debugger pane to know what's the key it's waiting for (let's say "15981"), then go to my web browser and manually add XDEBUG_SESSION_START=15981 as parameter to the URL.
Since the key changed every run, it's really a pain to work like that, and I don't talk about page redirection, etc...

Is anyone having a thought on that?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [bookmarklets](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) to do that. Even better -- look for xdebug extension for your browser -- it will set xdebug cookie that will be used on next page request. In any case: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+with+PhpStorm+as+Google+App+Engine+PHP+IDE

Comment: Thx for your comment. I've already tried the bookmarklets and can't get them to work and I've already checked the first confluence link many times. But the second seems to have many useful information. Will give it a try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You can start local App Endine server with App Engine For PHP run configuration, just as in [JetBrains tutorial](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+with+PhpStorm+as+Google+App+Engine+PHP+IDE#GettingStartedwithPhpStormasGoogleAppEnginePHPIDE-6.DebuggingApplicationLocally).
Then please enable Listen to incoming connections (that phone with small bug on toolbar near run configurations, or in menu `Run | Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections`). Then reload the page in browser. Debugger should stop on the first breakpoint or on the first line of code if that setting is enabled.

Also feel free to watch or vote the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28303) on bugtracker.

Answer (score -1):

@leneshka has the answer! I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to get PHPStorm to use the `xdebug.idekey` value I specified in xdebug.ini.

As soon as I enabled `Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections`, I was able to start debugging with my personal `xdebug.idekey` value.

Comment: Please, could you please tell me where is the xdebug.ini file?

Comment: It varies by OS. What OS are you using.

My VM is CentOS & it's `/etc/php.ini`.

Except that I'm using Vagrant/Puphpet & the values I added to the `config.yaml` ended up in a `/etc/php.d/zzzz_custom.ini`.

Comment: You talked about a xdebug.ini file (not the php.ini one) so I thought I was missing an important file.

Comment: Well, the same thing applies, it depends on the OS. CentOS: `/etc/php.d/xdebug.ini`, but again, my Vagrant/Puphpet setup puts any config settings in `/etc/php.d/zzzz_custom.ini` & it gets loaded.